# What was the significance of screw and bolts filled vomit?

Tags: analysis, closet-monster

In *Closet Monster*, Oscar was suffering from internalized homophobia and always has weird visions related to the trauma he had after seeing a gay guy getting raped by metal pole. But after having sex for the first time with Andrew, he sees all those weird visions again and vomits and visualizes it being full of screw and bolts:

[image]

What was the significance of having screw and bolts filled vomit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I haven't actually seen this movie myself.  However, based on the question, this is the sequence of events, as I understand it:

1. Oscar witnesses somebody being raped (I presume anally) by a metal pole.
2. Oscar later has (consensual?) anal intercourse with Andrew.
3. Oscar is dealing with homophobia and his emerging sexual identity, the mental trauma of which induces him to vomit.
4. He looks at his own vomit and imagines it filled with nuts & bolts.

To me, this seems like he's trying to deal with his feelings about homosexuality.  He witnessed this terrible rape involving a metal pole and now he's imagining his own internals filled with metal bits and bobs.  He's creating a mental association, presumably driven by his fear and homophobia.  He wants to pursue his desires, but every time he tries to engage in a  physical act, he's reminded of the unique aspects of the rape he witnessed, and thus is repulsed.

I don't know how it all ends, but assuming he's able to overcome his fear and accept himself for who he is, then I would expect the visions go away again by the end of the film.

Comment: "He wants to be close to Andrew" was not true, Andrew was just a hookup and that''s also not planned. Anyway nicely written answer

Comment: Thank you for the correction, I've edited that part out.